# Overriding stat_smooth color aesthetic of error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some results of a linear mixed effects modeling using stat_smooth in ggplot. Here is the data below:

```
structure(list(condition = c("mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd"), trial = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L), 
    n = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L), mean = c(1.21686746987952, 1.36458333333333, 1.27368421052632, 
    1.38144329896907, 1.29896907216495, 1.29896907216495, 1.35714285714286, 
    1.23157894736842, 1.16842105263158, 1.24489795918367, 1.09278350515464, 
    1.1530612244898, 1.23232323232323, 1.1010101010101, 1.24742268041237, 
    1.26530612244898, 1.15463917525773, 1.10204081632653, 1.1734693877551, 
    1.24242424242424, 1.30927835051546, 1.30612244897959, 1.07070707070707, 
    1.1340206185567, 1.04123711340206, 1.33333333333333, 1.28571428571429, 
    1.14141414141414, 1.21428571428571, 1.16161616161616, 1, 
    0.947916666666667, 1.24489795918367, 1.10204081632653, 1.12371134020619, 
    1.15463917525773, 1.32291666666667, 1.24489795918367, 1.22680412371134, 
    1.01052631578947, 1.21428571428571, 1.19587628865979, 1.25252525252525, 
    1.27272727272727, 1.11111111111111, 1.10416666666667, 1.24489795918367, 
    1.14285714285714, 1.14141414141414, 1.36082474226804, 1.08163265306122, 
    1.22222222222222, 1.14285714285714, 1.21428571428571, 1.1010101010101, 
    1.20408163265306, 1.08163265306122, 1.09183673469388, 1.05263157894737, 
    1.11111111111111, 1.23333333333333, 1.36842105263158, 1.18367346938776, 
    1.39393939393939, 1.44897959183673, 1.30208333333333, 1.37373737373737, 
    1.45918367346939, 1.37894736842105, 1.25510204081633, 1.41836734693878, 
    1.24242424242424, 1.39795918367347, 1.13265306122449, 1.38775510204082, 
    1.33673469387755, 1.28282828282828, 1.24242424242424, 1.26262626262626, 
    1.25, 1.14736842105263, 1.23711340206186, 1.33673469387755, 
    1.4020618556701, 1.17708333333333, 1.25510204081633, 1.20408163265306, 
    1.37755102040816, 1.16161616161616, 0.98989898989899, 1.15789473684211, 
    1.12121212121212, 1.21212121212121, 1.26530612244898, 1.26530612244898, 
    1.36363636363636, 1.2680412371134, 0.908163265306122, 1.19191919191919, 
    1.16326530612245, 1.09090909090909, 1.36734693877551, 1.23711340206186, 
    1.07216494845361, 1.20618556701031, 1.1530612244898, 1.33673469387755, 
    1.2020202020202, 1.17171717171717, 1.27551020408163, 1.1734693877551, 
    1.16161616161616, 1.20408163265306, 1.42424242424242, 1.17171717171717, 
    0.897959183673469, 1.1530612244898, 1.20408163265306, 1.16161616161616, 
    1.22222222222222), sd = c(1.01270216615919, 1.06740996579933, 
    0.983286989373624, 1.10343496796247, 1.04248249839034, 1.10080414218433, 
    0.976528672094517, 0.961521750220876, 1.00691895318118, 0.985055595163442, 
    0.969132711788442, 0.9984734824631, 0.901566469283538, 0.952921924280515, 
    1.06096386832771, 1.01077718804871, 0.982558375975348, 0.879195929729509, 
    0.873734846236235, 0.893181759171397, 0.928269276017068, 
    1.02954462223916, 0.90635539784038, 0.964244803583153, 0.956529379375379, 
    0.96890428330361, 1.01534616513362, 0.903621974984856, 1.03794006938207, 
    0.933580672236134, 0.908153218373, 0.92189497822539, 0.963896992505289, 
    0.924910649553274, 0.904361330336255, 0.971898980792747, 
    0.978664951717031, 1.01596761546119, 0.907206732218637, 1.01577699891962, 
    1.09591556601549, 0.98572282338195, 0.929597612569319, 0.987867026272032, 
    0.843811673650921, 0.888276470317265, 0.953141571572508, 
    0.885158265305801, 0.98984745279158, 1.01227432680809, 0.904438874716276, 
    0.96421222530079, 0.786483757639615, 0.864536107061105, 0.931259291091298, 
    1.06450882796424, 0.892967592579379, 0.953417452666471, 0.86747887401625, 
    0.957131011535323, 1.00616079756756, 1.04222176325741, 0.998420802299375, 
    1.01838389195404, 1.08525686046551, 1.10615304610325, 1.02604708673686, 
    0.986176280711472, 1.09329627847148, 0.934021617112209, 1.07380688416949, 
    0.937766659664192, 1.00246907470482, 0.959357120460447, 0.948494771287258, 
    1.01477616800704, 1.0404120459291, 0.937766659664192, 0.975054771730627, 
    0.99472291830968, 1.07157093918955, 0.997634659627134, 0.983826712918473, 
    0.931618146631988, 0.984028151786712, 0.96656714786713, 0.896260083679568, 
    1.04057187015492, 0.944447475955216, 0.897785819362251, 0.85447245730401, 
    0.93974298779873, 0.895256516343589, 1.0507829227218, 0.879913543177558, 
    0.952489171340722, 1.00535507738068, 0.838343170806987, 0.911119155682944, 
    0.970639894696112, 0.926821527972042, 0.988467053323476, 
    0.965802730421356, 0.938165571301387, 0.900672715366789, 
    0.934472019364842, 0.907515897461169, 1.02000198058829, 0.958744970882205, 
    0.982114405800246, 0.930862699345403, 0.986718646777997, 
    0.896260083679568, 0.969861226038888, 0.869440402252777, 
    0.830970069285778, 0.956281897966215, 0.907689756634026, 
    0.865519434779506, 0.863731292724622)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -120L), groups = structure(list(
    condition = c("mean", "odd"), .rows = structure(list(1:60, 
        61:120), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

My model looks something like below:

```
TD_PE_analysis_pref1 <- lmer(PE ~  trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref1)
```

Right now, when I run the code below my lines are the correct colors. I want to override the automatic color scheme of the error smoothing though and I can't seem to make it work.

```
plot <- ggplot(TD_PE_summ_Stats1, aes(x=trial,y=mean, colour=condition)) +
  stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.1, se=TRUE, aes(fill=condition), alpha=0.3) + 
   scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorchid4","darkorchid")) +
 geom_abline(
    aes(intercept = intercept_mean, slope = slope_mean),
    color = "darkorchid4"
  ) +
  geom_abline(
    aes(intercept = intercept_odd, slope = slope_odd),
    color = "darkorchid"
  ) +

  theme_bw()
```

How would I go overriding the automatic color scheme for this portion of the figure?
[image]

Comment: Add a `scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorchid4", "darkorchid"))` to apply the colors to the error ribbons